# Understanding objects in Python

Tags: python, object, object-model

I am a little confused by the object model of Python. I have two classes, one inherits from the other.

```
class Node():
  def __init__(identifier):
    self.identifier = identifier

class Atom(Node):
  def __init__(symbol)
    self.symbol = symbol
```

What I am trying to do is not to override the **__*init*__**() method, but to create an instance of atom that will have attributes **symbol** and **identifier**.

Like this:

```
Atom("Fe", 1) # will create an atom with symbol "Fe" and identifier "1"
```

Thus I want to be able to access Atom.identifier and Atom.symbol once an instance of Atom is created.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> class Node(object):
...     def __init__(self, id_):
...             self.id_ = id_
... 
>>> class Atom(Node):
...     def __init__(self, symbol, id_):
...             super(Atom, self).__init__(id_)
...             self.symbol = symbol
... 
>>> a = Atom("FE", 1)
>>> a.symbol
'FE'
>>> a.id_
1
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.Atom'>
>>>
```

It's a good idea to **inherit from object** in your code.

Comment: @Santa Atom's `__init__` should pass any extra arguments it gets that it doesn't need up to its superclass. Adding the `id_` parameter to Atom's `__init__` violates the DRY principle. Imagine adding more classes that inherit from Node as well, using the `id_` parameter and passing it up, and a Molecule class that inherits from Atom (even though it technically fails the "is a" test). Now you want to add a location parameter to the Node `__init__` and you have to change it in the `__init__` of Node, the `__init__` of all its subclasses, the `__init__` of all the subclasses of its subclasses, etc

Comment: @user470379 Like I said, it's a proof of concept. There is no need to over-engineer it.

Answer (score 6):

You have to call the `__init__`-method of the super-class manually.

```
class Atom(Node):
  def __init__(self, symbol, identifier)
    Node.__init__(self, identifier)
    self.symbol = symbol
```

Answer (score 3):

When creating a class you need to use the self word in the declaration. After that you can define the other arguments. To inherit call the super **init** method:

```
>>> class Node():
...   def __init__(self, identifier):
...     self.identifier = identifier
...
>>>
>>> class Atom(Node):
...   def __init__(self, symbol, identifier):
...     Node.__init__(self, identifier)
...     self.symbol = symbol
...
>>>
>>>
>>> fe = Atom("Fe", 1)
>>> fe.symbol
'Fe'
>>> fe.identifier
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two missing things in your code:

1. methods belonging to a class have to have an explicit `self` parameter, which you are missing
2. Your derived 'Atom' class also needs to accept the parameter it needs to use to initialize the base class.

Something more like:

```
class Node():
  def __init__(self, identifier):
    self.identifier = identifier

class Atom(Node):
  def __init__(self, identifier, symbol)
    Node.__init__(self, identifier)
    self.symbol = symbol
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Node(): 
  def __init__(self, identifier): 
    self.identifier = identifier 

class Atom(Node): 
  def __init__(self, symbol, *args, **kwargs)
    super(Atom, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.symbol = symbol
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) for an explanation of the `*args` and `**kwargs`. By using [`super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super), you can access the base class (superclass) of the Atom class and call it's `__init__`. Also, the `self` parameter needs to be included as well.

Comment: It's good practice to invoke the base class `__init__` method before doing any other initialization, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Node(object): 
  def __init__(self, identifier): 
    self.identifier = identifier 

class Atom(Node): 
  def __init__(self, symbol, *args, **kwargs)
    super(Atom, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.symbol = symbol
```

Points:

- Node should inherit from `object`.
- Use `super` to call parent classes' `__init__` functions.
- Class member functions take `self` as the first parameter in Python.